# Django POST multipart/form-data unexpectedly parsing field as array

Tags: django, multipartform-data, django-2.2

I am testing an endpoint in the following manner:

```py
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from django.urls import reverse
import json


client = APIClient()
response = client.post(list_url, {'name': 'Zagyg Co'})
```

I find that the model object is being created with a name of `[Zagyg Co]` instead of `Zagyg Co`.

Inspecting the request object reveals the following:

```py
self._request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']
#=> 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg; charset=utf-8'
self._request.body
#=> b'--BoUnDaRyStRiNg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nZagyg Co\r\n--BoUnDaRyStRiNg--\r\n'
self._request.POST
#=> <QueryDict: {'name': ['Zagyg Co']}>
```

Using JSON like so:

```
response = client.post(
    list_url, 
    json.dumps({'name': 'Zagyg Co'}), 
    content_type='application/json',
)
```

sets the name correctly. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.data` is a Django [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). When the data is sent as a multipart form it handles potential multiple values of the same field by putting it in a list.

Using its `dict` method or using dictionary access syntax returns the last value stored in the relevant key(s):

```py
request.data['name']
#=> 'Zagyg Co'
request.dict()
#=> {'name': 'Zagyg Co'}
```

Which is great if it's guaranteed that each key has a single value. For list values there's `getlist`:

```py
request.data.getlist('name')
#=> ['Zagyg Co']
```

For mixes of keys with single and multiple values it seems like manual parsing is required.